# I get the same code when overriding C# Equals method. How should I collapse duplicate code?

Tags: c#

I have 2 custom sealed classes: `Line` and `ColoredLine`. Both implement the `IEquals<T>` interface. But when I am overriding `IEquals` method, I get this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) 
{
    if (obj == null) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (obj == this) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(obj is ColoredLine)) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    return this.Equals((ColoredLine)obj);
}
```

and

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) 
{
    if (obj == null) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (obj == this) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (!(obj is Line)) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    return this.Equals((Line)obj);
}
```

The difference in only a type. Should I collapse it?

Comment: A `ColoredLine` is a `Line`, so why it doesn't inherit from it and also uses the same `Equals`?

Comment: Does `ColoredLine` inherit `Line`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, there is something to think about.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine it is not.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to the MS [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods)

```
return Equals(obj as ColoredLine);
```

is short enough

Answer (score 1):

I would let `ColoredLine` inherit from `Line` and also use `Line.Equals` to check if two colored-lines are equal, so like this:

```
public class Line: IEquatable<Line>
{
    public int Length { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return obj is Line l && this.Equals(l);
    }
    public bool Equals(Line? other)
    {
        return Length == other?.Length;
    }
}

public class ColoredLine: Line, IEquatable<ColoredLine>
{
    public System.Drawing.Color Color { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        return obj is ColoredLine cl && this.Equals(cl);
    }
    public bool Equals(ColoredLine? other)
    {
        return base.Equals(other) && Color == other?.Color;
    }
}
```

Remember that you also should override `GetHashCode` whenever you override `Equals`.